# iPhone 3GS: Right audio channel broken?

Tags: iphone, ear-phones

Recently, my iPhone 3GS has stopped playing music out the right earphone. I have tried other earphones, but the same thing happened. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Perhaps cleaning the jack out would help. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69630/what-can-be-done-when-the-headphones-wont-stay-seated-in-an-iphone. Also, perhaps this will help. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/47869/no-audio-on-the-right-channel

Answer (score 1):

My theory: Obviously, you have tried with several headphones, and the situation has not changed. Your headphone jack might have become dirty.

In some cases, this blocks the connections from one ore more audio channels to the headphone. You might want to try to clean it gently, e.g. with a cotton swab. You can find more info on how to do this [here](http://www.popularmechanics.com/technology/how-to/gadgets/4258816) or [google a bit](https://www.google.com/search?q=clean%20iphone%20headphone%20jack). Good luck!

PS: I did overlook the comment on this question, which I virtually duplicated with this answer. Nevertheless, have you tried to fix your iPhone jack with the methods described?