# MacBook Air: audio jack left channel failing

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, headphones

I have a MacBook Air 2012. I listen to audio by plugging EarPods into the audio jack.

This morning I noticed that I no longer have sound coming out of the left headphone. Well, There is a little, but it is < 10% what it should be.  I tried a different set of headphones and got the same result.

Is there any option for repairing the headphone port?

I'm guessing it is soldered onto the motherboard, and there will be absolutely no chance of a repair, and I will have to use a USB soundcard.

π

Comment: Have you tried giving the socket a blast with a can of compressed air? Could be a tiny wedge of non-conductive cruft like paper or plastic stuck in there.

Answer (score 1):

Some how my software had panned the audio to the right channel only.

God only knows why my machine decided to pan itself fully to the right!?

Anyway, if you think you need a repair, double check it's not software as I found on the [Apple discussions](https://discussions.apple.com/message/20990160#20990160).

Comment: @bmike, why have you edited out the link?  I guess it makes some sense to paraphrase the linked page in case one day it goes down (unlikely as it is an Apple forum), but that is a useful link. What if the conversation evolves on the original thread?

Comment: Oops - I meant to edit the text to explain the link, not bypass it entirely.

Comment: Fantastic, the world makes sense again :-)

Comment: Also - good information on the causes of this are over on this question. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/47869/no-audio-on-the-right-channel

Comment: I think you may have nailed it with that link. One of the answers points the finger at 'Audio MIDI setup' -- I was fiddling with that for the first time last night!!!